# how to create table with ID number compose of letter and number

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

how to create table with ID number compose of letter and number. example "AS-0001" so that everytime i will search a record i will only use the ID number.

Comment: What you have tried and what output you have got?

Comment: Just do it? You'd have to store the value in a `varchar` field...

Comment: With slight modification all are on same notes - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14678538/what-type-to-use-for-an-id-number-composed-of-letters-and-numbers-which-will-inc  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14680122/how-to-auto-increment-id-numbers-with-letters-and-numbers  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14686875/how-to-create-table-with-id-number-compose-of-letter-and-number http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14686346/how-to-create-auto-increment-id-number

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE `table_name` (
id VARCHAR(7),
randomDataField VARCHAR(255),
PRIMARY KEY (id)
)";
```

Then id will be a var char, so you can store both numbers and letters.

Although, this ID would not auto increment and you'd need to manually assign the ids.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE `AS-0001` (
id VARCHAR(7),
randomDataField VARCHAR(255),
PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```